# name of plot for discrete joint probability (table) visualizing black squares of varying size per cell

Tags: probability-distributions, graphing-functions

I was wondering what is the name of a specific plot type used for discrete joint probabilities.

This plot has a table structure and each cell is a black square of varying size, with size proportional to the amount of probability.

I need that name to do some Google searches in order to find JavaScript libraries that support that!

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Geographical Information Systems, the phrase seems to be ["graduated symbols"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22graduated%20symbols%22&tbm=isch).

Not that it affects your search, but presumably the side of each square is proportional to the square-root of the probability